# Splitting configuration in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am trying to split the configuration in Fluent NHibernate between two classlibraries (dll's).
The first classlibrary would configure certain listeners in NHibernate (for auditing and security) and the second would map/automap the entities. Any good ideas for how to pass the Fluent config between the libraries?
One idea I have is using Castle Windsor (part of my infrastructure already) and installers to pass the config via the container between the libraries. Does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a similar scenario where configure the mappings somewhere else. I dont pass the config around, i just take the mappings as a whole from different providers.

For example:

```
Fluently.Configure()
   .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(Container.Resolve<IAutoMapProvider>().Get())



public class AutoMapProvider : IAutomapProvider
{
    ...
    public static AutoPersistenceModel Get()
    {
        return AutoMap
            .AssemblyOf<MyObjectBase>(new MyConfiguration())
            .IgnoreBase<MyObjectBase>()
            .Conventions.Setup(c =>
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The Container here being an Castle Windsor object I guess?

Comment: @Konstantin the code is a derivation of production code i wrote. The container used is influenced by Castle's but my own abstraction

Comment: I went your way, pulling services with config/mappings contributions from the IOC container